# UItextField opens ui keyboard and no physical keyboard support in Swift Playground MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, swift-playground

When I use a UITextField in my macOS playground I keep getting the UI keyboard, which I do not wan't, and the physical mac keyboard doesn't do anything? How do I fix this because I want to use the users input from the physical keyboard. If anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate help!

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem? I would like to achieve similar thing

Comment: To fix this, if I recall correctly, you need to change the project from an iOS project to a macOS project and use NSViews and NSTextfields instead of UIViews and UITextfield.